# Difference between $\bigcup\mathscr{F}_x$ and $\mathscr{F}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

I have started reading scheme theory form "The Geometry of Schemes" written by Eisenbud and Harris.

Let $\mathscr{F}_x=\lim\limits_{\longrightarrow \\ x\in U}\mathscr(U)$, which is the disjoint union of all open sets $U$ containing $x$, with this equivalence relation: $\sigma\sim\tau$, if $\sigma \in \mathscr{F}(U)$ and $\tau\in \mathscr{F}(V)$ and there exists an open neighborhood of $x$, such as $W\subset U\cap V$ so that $res_{U,W}(\sigma)=res_{V,W}(\tau)$. (Where $res_{U,W}$ and $res_{V,w}$ are restriction maps.)

My problem is that I don't understand the difference between $\bigcup\mathscr{F}_x$ and $\mathscr{F}(U)$. My attempt: Let $\rho$ and $\sigma$ be two different global section of $\mathscr{F}(U)$.  If $\rho$ and $\sigma$ represent the same element in $\bigcup\mathscr{F}_x$, it means that for all members of $U$, such as $y$, we have $\rho_y=\sigma_y$. For all $y\in U$ we define $U_y$ to be the open neighborhood of $y$, where $\rho|_{U_y}=\sigma|_{U_y}$. These $U_y$s form an open covering for $U$. If from the previous sentence we can conclude that $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are the same, then they would represent the same member in $\mathscr{F}(U)$ as well. However I'm not sure if it's true that if two sections of a sheaf agree on an open covering, then we can say they are the same in $\mathscr{F}(U)$

Comment: An example may help you. Let $\mathcal{F}$ the sheaf of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb{C}$. Then $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is the set of holomorphic functions which are defined on $U$, whereas $\mathcal{F}_0$ is the set of holomorphic functions which are defined in a neighborhood of the origin, it turns out that they are the same as the set of power series with a positive convergence radius. Clearly these sets are different, because you can find holomorphic functions in a neighborhood of the origin which does not extend to the whole $U$.

Comment: @Roland Thank you very much

Comment: Is the last sentence of my original post true? That if restrictions of two sections agree on an open covering, they are the same in $\mathscr{F}(U)$?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what is denoted $\bigcup_{x\in U}\mathcal{F}(U)$ : the union in which set ?

Comment: Anyway, if you have two sections $\sigma,\tau\in\mathcal{F}(U)$ such that for all $x\in U$, $\sigma_x=\tau_x$ then this is true that $\sigma=\tau$.

Comment: @Roland I meant union on open sets of an arbitrary covering of $U$, but I wanted to conclude what you answered in the third reply.Thank you very much 